# How to use Random Randint for List ?

Tags: python, list, text, random

I wrote 3 Questions and I want to use Random Randint to pick and display one by one randomly. I don't know how to use Random Randint to use that in my Code.

Comment: When you say "one by one", do you want to pick with replacement (that is, each time there's a 1/3 chance of each), without replacement (that is, each one only shows up once, so after 3 choices there's nothing left), or some hybrid (e.g., pick all 3 in random order, then repeat all 3 in random order again, etc.)?

Answer (score 10):

You wouldn't use `random.randint()` **at all**. You'd use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) instead:

```
import random

questions = [question1, question2, question3]
random_question = random.choice(questions)
```

The function picks one element at random from a sequence.

If you need to produce questions at random *without repetition*, you want to do something different; you would use [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to randomize the whole list of questions, then just pick one from that list (perhaps removing it from the list) every time you need a new question. That produces a random *sequence* of questions.

```
import random

questions = [question1, question2, question3]
random.shuffle(questions)

for question in questions:
    # questions are iterated over in random order
```

or

```
questions = [question1, question2, question3]
random.shuffle(questions)

while questions:
    next_question = questions.pop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `randint`, use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice). This function will select a random item from a list.

```
import random

l = [1,2,3]

>>> random.choice(l)
2
>>> random.choice(l)
1
>>> random.choice(l)
1
>>> random.choice(l)
3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you *need* to use [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) because of an assignment, you can look at how [`choice`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/random.py#l250) works. Slightly simplified, it's this:

```
def choice(seq):
    i = randrange(len(seq))
    return seq[i]
```

And `randint(a, b)` is just "an alias for `randrange(a, b+1)`".

So, you know how to use `choice` from [Martijn Pieter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26370109/908494), you know what `choice` does, you should be able to figure out from there how to use `randint` from there.

Answer (score 2):

If [*"you want to pick with replacement (that is, each time there's a 1/3 chance of each)"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370089/how-to-use-random-randint-for-list#comment41397449_26370089):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random

questions = ["question1", "question2", "question3"]
while True: # infinite loop, press Ctrl + C to break
    print(random.choice(questions))
```

*"without replacement (that is, each one only shows up once, so after 3 choices there's nothing left)"*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random

questions = ["question1", "question2", "question3"]
random.shuffle(questions)
while questions: # only `len(questions)` iterations
    print(questions.pop())
```

*"or some hybrid (e.g., pick all 3 in random order, then repeat all 3 in random order again, etc."*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random

questions = ["question1", "question2", "question3"]
while True: # infinite loop, press Ctrl + C to break
    random.shuffle(questions)
    for q in questions: # only `len(questions)` iterations
        print(q)
```