# How to use RandInt in a list?

Tags: python

I have 3 names in a list that I only want to print one of them at random. How can I do that using random.randint()

```
jobs = [surgeon, soccer player, teacher]
```

I tried only writing `random.randint(jobs)` but I get the error of missing positional argument b, so now I am lost. I only want to do it with randint since I already know about random.choice()

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. Have you checked the documentation for `random.randint()` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Random Randint for List ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370089/how-to-use-random-randint-for-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random.randint` takes two parameters `a` and `b` and returns a random integer in the range `a...b` (inclusive).

You want to call the function where `a = 0` and `b = len(jobs) - 1` so that the function returns a random index of the list.

```
>>> jobs = ['surgeon', 'soccer player', 'teacher']
>>> random.randint(0, len(jobs)-1)
1
>>> jobs[random.randint(0, len(jobs)-1)]
'teacher'
```

If you want to get a random integer between `a...b` non-inclusive, then you can use `random.randrange`:

```
>>> jobs[random.randrange(0, len(jobs))]
'surgeon'
```

This also has the added advantage of not needing the first parameter and assuming the lower bound is 0:

```
>>> jobs[random.randrange(len(jobs))]
'soccer player'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you should use `random.choice()` like so:

```py
>>> jobs = ['surgeon', 'soccer player', 'teacher']
>>> random.choice(jobs)
'soccer player'
```